# Image behind another

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to display some images using sass/css and it seems that the images from the body are hiding behind the image header and don't understand why.... Please can someone help me ? I guess it must be due to either the size of the images or position.

Maybe something is wrong in the stylesheet ?

```
body {
  font-size: $font_size_body;
  header {
    .image-container {
      img {
        width: 100vw;
        position: absolute;
      }
    }
    .container_1 {
      nav {
        .logo-conatiner {
          img {
            width: 10rem;
            position: relative;
            top: 20px;
            left: 25px;
          }
        }
          .list_links{
              position: relative;
              display: flex;
              justify-content: flex-end;
              top: 0.1vh;
              li{
                  margin: 0 3rem 0 3rem;
                  a{
                      color: $color_white;
                      text-decoration: none;
                      font-family: $font_2;
                      font-weight: $font_2_weight_bold;
                      &:hover{
                          color: black;
                          font-family: $font_1;
                          background-color: $color_white;
                          border-radius: 50px;
                          padding: 0.8rem;
                          cursor: pointer;
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
        
      }
      h1{
          font-family: $font_1;
          font-weight: $font_1_weight;
          font-size: 50px;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          position: relative;
          color: #FFF;
          text-align: center;
          top: 22vh;
          
      }
      .arrow-to-bottom{
          position: relative;
          left: 50vw;
          top: 30vh;
      }
    }
  }

  main{
      .section_1{
          width: 100vw;
          height: 50vh;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's going to be awfully difficult to debug your CSS without the corresponding HTML or any specifics about which image in the layout has a stacking problem.

Comment: Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

At line 7, you declared a position absolute for the header image. Position absolute takes the element (the header image in your case) out of the flow of the document, which makes this image to place over almost everything else.
You can fix this problem with `z-index: auto;`. Simply it makes the image to not establish a new local stacking context, so its stack level in the current stacking context is 0.
(You can also use a negative z-index if that works for you. => `z-index: -1;`)